# Drawing strings with custom fonts draws an assortment of dashes

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt

I'm trying to add a custom font into my Java program with TTFs, but for whatever reason, my strings are drawn simply as an assorment of dashes, and occasionally, dots. For example, if I use this code to define my font:

```
font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 
         ac.class.getResourceAsStream("/fonts/verdana.TTF"));
```

Then the main menu looks like this:

[image]

Rather than this:

[image]

Note: I'm using the code

```
Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 30);
```

to define the font in the second screenshot.

Comment: It appears the first is using a font size of 1px.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the method [deriveFont](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28float%29) to resize the font that you have just loaded:

```
font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 
     ac.class.getResourceAsStream("/fonts/verdana.TTF")).deriveFont(30f);
```

Comment: You, sir, are amazing. I suppose the dashes were still the letters, just in a very tiny format?

Comment: Yeah. As @Andrew Thompson and shuangwhywhy pointed out, they had point size of 1.

Answer (score 4):

The [API spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont(int%2C%20java.io.InputStream)) says:

> Returns a new `Font` using the specified font type and input data. The new `Font` is created with a ***point size of 1*** and style PLAIN. This base font can then be used with the `deriveFont` methods in this class to derive new Font objects with varying sizes, styles, transforms and font features. This method does not close the `InputStream`.
>
> To make the `Font` available to `Font` constructors the returned `Font` must be registered in the `GraphicsEnviroment` by calling `registerFont(Font)`.